# Java Swing: Deselect items from JList

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlist

I'm making a fairly simple Swing app that has the classic "add or remove files" panels, which I'm trying to make as dynamic as possible. Right now, I've set up the Remove button to only enable when a list item is selected (via a ListSelectionListener). However, I also want the user to have the ability to deselect that list item by clicking anywhere but on it. The only non-clunky solution I've found is to have a focusLost action, but that also disables the Remove button before it has a chance to work. Is there a way to:

1. Listen for a mouse click on anywhere except the list options AND the Remove button or
2. Have the focusLost action ignore the user clicking the remove button?

Edit: Here's a simplified version of the GUI code to test with:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
}
                     
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    removeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    jList1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            jList1FocusLost(evt);
        }
    });
    jList1.addListSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
            jList1ValueChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

    addButton.setText("Add");

    removeButton.setText("Remove");
    removeButton.setEnabled(false);

    jTextField1.setText("Placeholder text field");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(addButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(removeButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(addButton)
                .addComponent(removeButton))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}

private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
    removeButton.setEnabled(!jList1.isSelectionEmpty());
}                                   

private void jList1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 
    jList1.clearSelection();
}                                

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
               
private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JButton removeButton;        
}
```

The methods I'm playing with are:

```java
private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
    removeButton.setEnabled(!jList1.isSelectionEmpty());
}                                   

private void jList1FocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 
    jList1.clearSelection();
}
```

Comment: If your Swing application is fairly simple, you should have no problem posting a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Done. The code is still pretty substantial since it's an entire auto-generated GUI, but I included the whole thing to let other people test things if they want.

Comment: The normal UI is to hold the Control key when clicking on a selected item to deselect it. It doesn't make sense to click on some other component. Or you add a "Clear" button to remove all the selections.